# How to make a visual space e.g. like an album & upload pictures to a website?

Tags: php

I want to upload my pictures on my web site. The way I want to do is like there appear photo albums like images on my web page that contain my pictures. How do I do that?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: But which server-side language? You won't be able to make an upload feature without something happening server-side. (JavaScript is client-side, and HTML is not a programming language).

Comment: OH OK, I was actually mentioning languages I used in development. Than I can use PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an upload form, and store the uploaded files (filesystem and/or database). Then display them to the user.

[Basic upload form example](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp) from w3schools